# Infer union of strings from an array of objects, while creating an object

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Presume I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface Foo {
  items: Item[];
  defaultItem: Foo[number]['id']
}
```

If I have the following code, I would like `defaultItem` to only be one of the `id` keys set in `items`, like so:

```
const myObj: Foo = {
  items: [{ id: 'bar', name: 'Bar' }, { id: 'baz', name: 'Baz'} ],
  defaultItem: 'fooooo' // error, can only be 'bar' and 'baz'
}
```

Is this doable in typescript?

What I have tried:

1. In my real implementation, `Foo` looks something like this:

```
interface Foo<TItems extends Item[]> {
  items: TItems;
  defaultItem: TItems[number]['id']
}
```

This ends up inferring `string`.

2. In `myObj` I add `as const` to the array `items`. Didn't work.

What are my options?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNwFEhwYQXW0iMEC+BAqEixEKAGIB7SQB4AKuggZKyCAA9IIEiqgQ4JSSAA2ATzSYA2gF0AfDmbFMlCgqdNCyEhHgBXI2EUMF0DKCxAfDAAjaCsLAHJSOKt3AXxBfARDamQEXThIKUlkAF5kGUyQbJDVDQgtHT0DYzNA6xsAChhpCkKZEJsAShK7Lsl0iuyMEwB5SIArEpy8gul2vA9gJwoLByJsYnJkOMi4KDiAGmRWdgo4gCFTuOQ+c92cA9uTgC8Lq7YOI4PH7PV4eKygoheXz+QJkOKjSS-AD0SNUUCgkiglwQcBAyEMpmQ0SOJzOyFxJBJcB+-AGDCAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Is there a way to avoid the function? The `Foo` interface will be used to type react props, so that wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: What about [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP86LW)?

Comment: @wonderflame That works! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Typescript version `>= 5.0.0`, we will use [const type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) that were introduced in `5.0.0`. Basically, it does the same thing as what [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) does.

Since, both `const assertion` and `const type parameters` turn the arrays to `readonly`, we will need to update the `extends` conditions as well, moreover you mentioned that the interface will be used as a react component props, thus the following code will be in react context:

```
interface Foo<TItems extends readonly Item[]> {
  items: TItems;
  defaultItem: TItems[number]['id'];
}

const Comp = <const T extends readonly Item[]>(props: Foo<T>) => {
  return null;
};
```

Testing:

```
const Wrapper = () => (
  <Comp
    items={
      [
        { id: 'bar', name: 'Bar' },
        { id: 'baz', name: 'Baz' },
      ]
    }
    defaultItem="fooo" // expected error
  />
);
```

For the typescript version `< 5.0.0` just a `const assertion` will work, since we updated the `extends` conditions:

```
const Comp = <T extends readonly Item[]>(props: Foo<T>) => {
  return null;
};

const Wrapper = () => (
  <Comp
    items={
      [
        { id: 'bar', name: 'Bar' },
        { id: 'baz', name: 'Baz' },
      ] as const
    }
    defaultItem="fooo" // expected error
  />
);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BJBvAbyrjmAAmALjgBnGFDoBzCpT60UIJCPGTaMqgF8qNeo2ZpWAMQgQAPABUOSEKLhIAHg1oC7RFAIi0ANgE92nADaALoAfHA8cvycoiJWMbJ8AkjMAK7eMNYgcVmigbSpIABGjMGB+IL4wbLa1JRoXuJwAMK4YHAAvHBmDbRNFvZOSC5uqJ4+-lkhoQAUYDhgsXAm5hahAJSd4ZF8RDCpULRwBd7eNbJUvU0A6lAoYGCMnXAzmx3hM7zdreBffMAxDo7PggwJ-EF8Lj8YQEIooKD4AA0x0UygIACF4fg4JpEeCIVDBCJ8HCAF5IlFKYmY8k4vFRCHBcG1CHJNIZLIdABEmFMEC5cAA9ILBo8MEgBPYoDgoF9BaEqOtSHAqEA)